# Plot 3 graph in R

Tags: r, plot

I'am trying to plot 3 curve in the same plot, but I've got a problem with the third plot relying to bike, it doesn't appear  : 
Any idea please?

```
# Define 3 vectors

cars <- c(1, 3, 6, 4, 9)
trucks <- c(2, 5, 4, 5, 12)
bike <- c(12, 15, 14, 15, 12)

# Calculate range from 0 to max value of cars and trucks

g_range <- range(0, cars, trucks)

# Graph autos using y axis that ranges from 0 to max 
# value in cars or trucks vector.  Turn off axes and 
# annotations (axis labels) so we can specify them ourself

plot(cars, type="o", col="blue", ylim=g_range, 
     axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)

# Make x axis using Mon-Fri labels
axis(1, at=1:5, lab=c("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri"))
```

Make y axis with horizontal labels that display ticks at every 4 marks. `4*0:g_range[2]` is equivalent to `c(0,4,8,12)`.

```
axis(2, las=1, at=4*0:g_range[2])

# Create box around plot
box()

# Graph trucks with red dashed line and square points
lines(trucks, type="o", pch=22, lty=2, col="red")

lines(bike, type="o", pch=23, lty=3, col="green")

# Create a title with a red, bold/italic font
title(main="Autos", col.main="red", font.main=4)

# Label the x and y axes with dark green text
title(xlab="Days", col.lab=rgb(0,0.5,0))
title(ylab="Total", col.lab=rgb(0,0.5,0))
c("cars","trucks"), cex=0.8, col=c("blue","red"), pch=21:22, lty=1:2);
```

Comment: Your y range goes from 0 to 12 while all the bike values are larger than 12. The line is drawn, actually, but ouside the plot area.

Comment: Can set the ylim to be the min and max of the combination of the two series of y values. Appears you forgot to include `bike` values in range in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `par(new=TRUE)` then set the y-axis to the right side for the third graph.

```
x <- 1:5
y1 <- rnorm(5)
y2 <- rnorm(5,20)
par(mar=c(5,4,4,5)+.1)
plot(x,y1,type="l",col="red")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(x, y2,,type="l",col="blue",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="")
axis(4)
mtext("y2",side=4,line=3)
legend("topleft",col=c("red","blue"),lty=1,legend=c("y1","y2"))
```

some sample graph from http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/r-graph-with-two-y-axes/

cheers,
Justin

Comment: You would improve the possibility that someone viewing such a plot will see that there is a difference by coloring the y-axis annotations: `plot(x,y1,type="l",col="red", col.axis="red")` and `axis(4, col="blue",col.axis="blue")`. Two-ordinate axes are generally seen as a probable source of confusion because the viewer will have difficulty resolving the differences in scale.